# How to add double quotes to a various strings in a same pattern in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file like this

```
CREATE TABLE ENTDTA.$$BAPWD (
    PERSID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    "PASSWORD" CHAR(10) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    UPDATE_IDENT     NUMBER(7, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL )
    ;

CREATE TABLE ENTDTA.$$BARTSPH (
    CLORDID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    CLORDLNID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    RTSTEPID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    HLDRSNCDE CHAR(6) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    HOLDCMNT VARCHAR2(256) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    HLDUNTDT DATE DEFAULT NULL ,
    UPDATE_IDENT     NUMBER(7, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL )
    ;

CREATE TABLE ENTDTA.$$BASRCTY (
    OTSRCTC CHAR(6) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    OTSRCTD CHAR(30) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    ORLNSTSCD CHAR(6) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    UPDATE_IDENT     NUMBER(7, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL )
    ;

CREATE TABLE ENTDTA.$$BAWPDFST (
    H1SCNS NUMBER(7, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    OTSRCTC CHAR(6) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    STYLEID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    CRTNAM CHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL ,
    CRTTIM TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
    LSTUPDNAM CHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL ,
    LSTUPDTIM TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
    UPDATE_IDENT     NUMBER(7, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL )
    ;
```

Whenever there is ENTDTA.$$something. The $$something should be enclosed in double quotes. The output should be like

```
CREATE TABLE ENTDTA."$$BAPWD" (
    PERSID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    "PASSWORD" CHAR(10) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    UPDATE_IDENT     NUMBER(7, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL )
    ;

CREATE TABLE ENTDTA."$$BARTSPH" (
    CLORDID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    CLORDLNID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    RTSTEPID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    HLDRSNCDE CHAR(6) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    HOLDCMNT VARCHAR2(256) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    HLDUNTDT DATE DEFAULT NULL ,
    UPDATE_IDENT     NUMBER(7, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL )
    ;

CREATE TABLE ENTDTA."$$BASRCTY" (
    OTSRCTC CHAR(6) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    OTSRCTD CHAR(30) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    ORLNSTSCD CHAR(6) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    UPDATE_IDENT     NUMBER(7, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL )
    ;

CREATE TABLE ENTDTA."$$BAWPDFST" (
    H1SCNS NUMBER(7, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    OTSRCTC CHAR(6) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL ,
    STYLEID NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,
    CRTNAM CHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL ,
    CRTTIM TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
    LSTUPDNAM CHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL ,
    LSTUPDTIM TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
    UPDATE_IDENT     NUMBER(7, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL )
    ;
```

How can I achieve that using `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: Sorry. I am doing it manually. But there are 1000s of strings with this pattern that needs to be quoted

Comment: So you've not even tried figuring out a `sed` or `awk` solution?

Comment: I am a beginner in sed and awk. Couldn't get any solutions.

Comment: From the main help page for this site: "Include details about what you have tried...". If you're not bothering to try to solve it yourself, you're unlikely to find anyone here willing to do your job for you.

Comment: `sed '/\bENTDTA\./s/\$\$\S\+/"&"/'`

Comment: Can you please elaborate how it works.

Comment: This smells like homework.....

Comment: @coteyr Not necessarily. At my work I often need to change some scripts or manipulate other text. Cases like this one are popular.

Comment: @MatthewRock, yeah but you usually try "something" before posting to U&L.

Comment: `sed -i -e 's/\(\$\$[^ ]*\)/"\1"/'` which quotify only de `$$` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I will feed the bears just once. :)  Here is one possible solution using sed

```
sed -e 's/\(\$\$[a-zA-z]*\)/'\"'\1'\"'/g' YourFileName
```

Think about this in Three parts

1. Pattern Matching - You have to match some string `\(\$\$[a-zA-z]*\)`.
2. Reuse of Match using Groups - That is what the parens are about `\(` stuff in middle `\)`.  You are saying "Hey, once you match this string, I want to reuse this later.
3. The new string - The new string looks like `"\1"` where `\1` means the first pattern that you have to be matched in your regex.

FYI, as you can see I escaped a `"` by using `'\"'`.

I would advise that you take some tiny steps and work with some beginner sed scripts and decompose some sed recipes.

Comment: Or just `sed -e 's/\(\$\$[a-zA-z]*\)/"\1"/g'` — you overcomplicated the shell quoting. Which can be further simplified in sed to `sed -e 's/\$\$[a-zA-z]*/"&"/g'`